# Are Japanese women visiting middle eastern countries at risk of being seen as "easy"?

Tags: safety, middle-east, discrimination, female-travellers, japanese-visitors

I've heard that in some (but not all!) areas in the middle east, there's a stereotype held by some (but not all!) that western women are easy. From [The Arab myth of western women](http://www.guardian.co.uk/commentisfree/2010/nov/10/arab-myth-of-western-women) by Khaled Diab:

> In this view, western women are oversexed, promiscuous and have
>   revolving doors in their knickers. "A typical Egyptian male is a firm
>   believer that any western woman is an easy catch and would not mind at
>   all having sex with complete strangers," observes Ahmed, an old
>   college friend.
>
> This can lead to hassle and harassment for western women travelling or
>   living in Egypt and some other Arab countries, although in places like
>   Yemen men will either just stare or the western woman will become
>   invisible like the local women, as my wife found while travelling
>   alone through the country. Of course, given the potent mix of sexual
>   repression, poverty, ignorance, the growing disappearance of the
>   traditional model of respect for women and the failure to replace it
>   with a modern equivalent, you don't have to be western to be harassed
>   on the streets.

Are Japanese women visiting such countries at risk of having the same stereotypes applied to them? If so, what can individuals do to avoid being perceived that way?

Comment: I think difficult to answer your question. Arab countries (I'm assuming you're confusing the Middle East with Arab countries) are _very_ different. The culture in the north African countries is very different from the culture in the Levant (Syria, Lebanon, Jordan..) which is in turn different from the culture in the Gulf countries. Even in the same country you'll see _huge_ differences between some regions and cities. If you make the question a bit more specific, I (and I think others as well) will be able to write a suitable answer.

Comment: @Adnan thanks for your comment. To be honest, one reason I used "middle east" rather than "arab countries" is that I didn't want to be accused (yet again) of being racist (not by you - by someone else!). Also, while I know people from various parts of the middle east (including Egypt, Jordan, and Iran (if that counts as "middle east")), I haven't yet taken as much an interest in its culture as that from other parts of the world.

Comment: I'm unaware of the nature of the accusations you faced previously, but I don't see how saying "Arab", "Jewish" or "Black" is considered racist. Regardless of that, your comment doesn't address the concerns raised in my comment. As it currently stands, your question is too broad to be answered in satisfying manner. Please try to narrow it.

Comment: Voted to close. Are you sure you are not projecting your opinion on japanese women on the middle east?

Comment: @Andrew Grimm:  at least 150 milion people living in what is usually qualified as "Middle East" are not Arabic.

Comment: Iranian's are not Arabic but are (arguably) "middle Eastern".

Comment: @Andra Your query in the comments sounds like a calculated gratuitous slur on Andrew. It's not obvious why you would make that statement (phrased as if it's a question). What response would you consider to be appropriate to such a provocative query?

Comment: As an Iranian/Persian citizen, surely Iran is one of countries located in the middle east: en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Middle_East. You can find all of them on the map. Iran,Turkey and Kurds (Non independent) are non Arabic nations of middle east and surely most people of Israel. It is only a strategic political classifying not ethnical or lingual or even cultural classifying.

Comment: @Andra while writing this question, I did happen to reflect upon what stereotypes westerners have about Japanese women. Are we guilty of having the same stereotypes about Japanese women that some people have about western women? But no, the stereotype that's held about Japanese women is more that they see westerners as preferable over Japanese men. Still a stereotype, but not the same one.

Comment: @AndrewGrimm I think all you are saying are too localized and general and related to some very narrow-minded people which can find them whole around the world not only in the west or middle east or Japan, male or female! It is important for all people who claim they are not like that bad dumb people and are open minded, that you ignore stereotypes and not repeating them for any reason times and times in public places. You are repeating doubtful cheap claims here about middle eastern men,western men,Japanese women and middle eastern culture!

Comment: All these stuffs can be only some offensive rumors that no one can find their correctness unless who have made them on purpose to humiliate different nations and spread hate talk to fire new wars and increase hate and sexism and racism.

Comment: All women and men are free humans to decide about their own relationships and there are only fanatic,misogyny and hatred people who spend their time to hear them and believe them and repeat them to force people to not forget them and use them! Have you ever asked yourself why there is nobody to say why many non native men prefer to try sex in the other countries easily?! Are they easy men?! I think in 21 century it is extra ugly to repeat cheap dirty rumors as a question in a public place and defend of it as a try to protect a special nation of gender discrimination combined with racism.

Comment: It doesn't work if you are honest in it but worse, It damages more! A woman who want to have sex with a stranger to get a real relaxation far from of her own country and all which is bothering her or with a man who will leave the country as soon as possible doesn't matter angry reactions or dirty minds of these narrow mined people even if they are the same who have slept with them! Surely it is only about whom choose themselves equal with men and not trying make money of this!

Comment: They are most powerful women who do not care to such rumors and do everything which they want even sex with a stranger during one hour and can say bye or stay in the relationship if they want! It doesn't mean they are preferring the other nations to their own men but they like to experience new things,new men and enjoy it. That's all! I think doesn't deserve more time to spend for it. Do not worry about women! They laugh at these kinds of stereotypes which are made by people who their anger are burning them because they have found that many women can separate sex and love.

Comment: Despite some problems, I think there's an interesting question at the heart of this, if we accept the assertion made by the linked source (and that's a 'big if' - maybe this question should be asked in the comments on that article).  So, to narrow this down: "*If* we can agree that there is a popular stereotype among many Egyptian men that 'Western' women are 'easy', is this stereotype also often directed at Japanese women?"  or perhaps "Do Japanese women encounter the same treatment and attitudes in Egypt as 'Western' women?"  'Bonus' if the answer holds for "Arab" and "East Asian"